# org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP 1.1(Java) to generate PDF files. 
It is working fine on windows machine but when I used Ubuntu machine I got this error

```
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported.  No ImagePreloader found
```

I am little bit confused. Please give me solution to sort out this problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got solution from stackoverflow only. I am giving special thanks to author of this post
 [Apache FOP in a Java Applet - No ImagePreloader found for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139301/apache-fop-in-a-java-applet-no-imagepreloader-found-for-data)

```
With reference from above post , To give precedence to XmlGraphics
API , 
  1. I have excluded XML-graphics API from FOP jar
  2. added new maven dependency XmlGraphics API and placed above FOP dependancy
  3. so that POM will give priority


   <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlgraphics-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avalon.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon-framework-impl</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thank you

Comment: I have fop.jar but it does not contain xmgraphics-commons and I still have this issue. can you help me ?

Comment: which version of FOP are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is a conflict between configuration files existing in `META-INF/services/` both in `fop` jar file and `xmlgraphics-commons` jar file.

If you're using maven and want to avoid exclusion that may sometimes cause troubles, you can use the **maven shade plugin** to build a jar and force the concatenation of configuration files in `META-INF/services/`. A snippet like this one works for me:

```
   <build>
        <finalName>desired_jar_name</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>my.main.class</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: That answer pointed me into the right direction. We encountered that problem with the SVG Image Preloader. The dirty solution was to abuse classpath precendence and load Apache FOP 2.7 *before* xmlgraphics-commons-2.7. We had different behaviours when starting it on our Test-Environments and Eclipse: it worked in Eclipse and nowhere else.

Comment: This has worked a while for me, but after another upgrade of FOP the problem came back.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent solution for gradle would be:

```
shadowJar{
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me, but this one worked:

Adding xml-apis-ext.jar from https://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/index.html

Comment: do you have some maven or gradle dependencies available?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same exception. Images were loading when testing in dev and local environments but not in production. Our issue was that image URLS were build using **http://**. What tricked us is that our server redirects **http** to **https** automatically thus when were check the image URLS manually they worked. However FOP doesn't follow redirects thus throwing the exception. So keep mind protocol as well when troubleshooting this exception/error.