# Where has org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation gone?

Tags: java, dom, svg, batik

In the [documentation for batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/dom-api.html), it shows how to get an instance of the DOM implementation from the class [org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SVGDOMImplementation.html).

However, after downloading Batik 1.8 from the same site, I cannot find this class anywhere.

I downloaded the 1.7 version and found it in batik-svg-dom.jar but it does not exist in the same jar within 1.8 (or as far as I can tell in any of the jars in that package).

Has this class been renamed / refactored / replaced? If so how do you get an instance of the DOM implementation in batik 1.8?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found the answer, embedded in the maillist thread posted in @Ajay's answer.

It seems that in order to solve [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1098), they have moved `SVGDOMImplementation` into package `org.apache.batik.anim.dom`, which lives in the jar file batik-anim-1.8.jar.

As at the time of writing, the batik web site had not yet been updated, and for some reason this change was also not highlighted in the release notes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having same issue, looks like we need to drop back to 1.7.. 1.8 is unstable as suggested in of the thread

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-batik-users/201503.mbox/%3C5515BC93.90402@ptc.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Apache Batik 1.8. The official binaries of that version are not compatible. To get the version 1.8 work I had to replace `fop-transcoder-allinone-1.1.jar` by `fop-transcoder-allinone-2.2.jar` which I took from Apache Batik 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Download binary of Apache Batik1.8 it makes life easier with above problem. Include only that in your project. That's enough. [Here](http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/xmlgraphics/batik/binaries/) is the link.

Note that binaries are nothing but source code compiled into Java Archive files (JARs) they are the one's that execute on JVM.

Comment: How does that help solve the problem? Whether using source or binary distributions, the `SVGDomImplementation` class is no longer in package ` org.apache.batik.dom.svg`.