# Apache FOP 2.0 - Why is no ImagePreloader found for SVG?

Tags: java, svg, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP 2.0 in a jsf application (with JBoss 7) to create pdf files. But I get the following error if I want to include a svg:

> Image not available. URI: image/svg.svg. Reason:
>   org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is
>   not supported. No ImagePreloader found for image/svg.svg (No context
>   info available): org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException:
>   The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for
>   image/svg.svg

The error only occur with svg files. Other image types (jpg or png) work correctly. So I did some research and found some approaches:

---

[Apache FOP in a Java Applet - No ImagePreloader found for data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139301/apache-fop-in-a-java-applet-no-imagepreloader-found-for-data)

I changed my pom so `xmlgraphics-commons` is loaded before `fop`, but it did not work. I am using `xmlgraphics-commons` in version 2.0.1 `batik` in version 1.8 and `avalon-framework` (api and impl) in version 4.3.1.

---

http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/FOP-1-0-images-fail-to-render-td7348.html

My last approache was to use the hints from the last post (from morjane), but it did not solved my problem.

---

Some have problems with barcode libraries but I am not using one.

If anyone can give me a hint or has an idea how to solve this error I would be very grateful. Please ask if more information are needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `xercesImpl` to my pom fixed the problem.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>xerces</groupId>
   <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
   <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It also fixed the following error I had using batik for `.svg` to `.eps` conversion:

> org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: null
>   Enclosed Exception: SAX2 driver class
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser not found.