# Images are not displayed in PDF generated by apache fop

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, jar, apache-fop

I am generating PDF files with the apache fop library (v2.2). If I run application from the Eclipse IDE all run without problems but if I generate *JAR* from the Eclipse IDE with library handling set to *Extract required libraries into generated JAR* and after that I will run JAR it will generate PDF files without images (text is visible as expected). First I thought that it is caused by invalid file paths, but If I use the base64 encoding of images directly in the XSL images are still not visible. If I generate *JAR* with library handling set to *Package required libraries into generated JAR* everything run OK but too slowly. Have you any idea which can be the reason of this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between extracting and packaging libraries into a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617420/difference-between-extracting-and-packaging-libraries-into-a-jar-file) - by the way, I've used FOP for a client - it's pretty cool!  If you need further elaboration/troubleshooting I can try and help!

Comment: Hindsight, the link provides some good information but doesnt really answer your question.  You *could* always put the jars required by the app in the lib directory so they'd be accessible and it would slow your build/deploy time?

Comment: Thank you for response, I build simple example and I got error 'SEVERE: Image not available. URI: template.JPG. Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for template.JPG (No context info available)'. So I think that problem is decribed here http://apache-fop.1065347.n5.nabble.com/FOP-cant-find-preloader-classes-td41075.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139301/apache-fop-in-a-java-applet-no-imagepreloader-found-for-data I will try to solve it on the evening and update current progress.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out Michal!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out following problems:

1. I was using my *java.util.logging.Logger* and did not see the results of the logger used in apache fop. I build simple testing application without this logger and got following error:

> 'SEVERE: Image not available. URI: image_name.jpg. Reason:
>   org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is
>   not supported. No ImagePreloader found for image_name.jpg(No context
>   info available)'

2. Description how to solve this problem for application build with maven is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26282077/6232262). I am using external JARs, so I only changed the order of adding JARs in *Java Build Path* menu in Eclipse and eveything works.

[image]